# include markup in highlightjs block

Tags: highlight.js

As far as I can tell, highlightjs strips any markdown from text it highlights, e.g. the `span` in:

```
<pre class="shexc">&lt;http://a.example/foo> {
  a:b foo:bar {
    <span style="font-weight: bold">x:y 1</span> # blah blah
  } .
}
</pre>
```

Is there any way to get it to pass spans without disabling it entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The span is real HTML - the browser knows that and will renders it - which is why you don't see it... use web inspector, it's not gone - it's still there.  If you want it to highlighted instead you need to encode it properly:

```
<pre class="shexc">&lt;http://a.example/foo> {
  a:b foo:bar {
    &lt;span style="font-weight: bold"&gt;x:y 1&lt;/span&gt; # blah blah
  } .
}
</pre>
```